# Getting the number of text lines in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to display the number of  text lines in a textbox through the label.But, the thing is if the last line is empty, the label has to display the line numbers with out that empty line.

For example if they are 5 line with the last line as empty, then the label should display the number of lines as 4.

Thanks..

```
private void txt_CurrentVinFilter_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   labelCurrentVinList.Text = string.Format("Current VIN List ({0})",  txt_CurrentVinFilter.Lines.Length.ToString());                       
}
```

Actually, above is the code...have to change to display only the no-empty lines in C# winforms.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you do need to actually *ask* a question for people to answer.

Comment: If you like an answer, accept it as one

Answer (score 19):

You can also do this in a shorter way using LinQ. To count the lines and exlcude the last line if it is empty:

```
var lines = tb.Lines.Count();
lines -= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Lines.Last()) ? 1 : 0;
```

And to count only non-empty lines:

```
var lines = tb.Lines.Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not count any empty lines at the end

```
int count = tb.Lines.Length;
while (count > 0 && tb.Lines[count - 1] == "") {
    count--;
}
```

Or, if you want to exclude also lines containing only whitespaces

```
int count = tb.Lines.Length;
while (count > 0 && tb.Lines[count - 1].Trim(' ','\t') == "" ) {
    count--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `WordWrap` is set to `true` and you want the number of lines that are displayed, try:

```
int count = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(int.MaxValue) + 1;
// Now count is the number of lines that are displayed, if the textBox is empty count will be 1
// And to get the line number without the empty lines:
if (textBox1.Lines.Length == 0)
    --count;
foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
    if (line == "")
        --count;
```