# Get TextBox line number

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to get a `TextBox` lines number in `C#` *winform* application. But unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606818/getting-the-number-of-text-lines-in-a-textbox) I want the real line number, whether it is a wrapped line or is a new line with `\r\n`.

`var lines = tb.Lines.Count();` will just get the lines number with carriage return.

So How can I get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand what you want, but generally you can use this code to count lines in your textbox:

```
public int LineNumber()
    {
        int LineNumber;
        LineNumber = textBoxNotePad.Lines.Length;
        return LineNumber;
    }
```

I hope it's useful

Comment: I think the original question was how to include _soft_ line breaks (i.e. wrapped lines) as well as _hard_ ones. Doesn’t look like this will solve it.